# ASP.NET MasterPage javascript error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I have this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#social-share').dcSocialShare({
                    buttons: 'twitter,facebook,linkedin,digg,stumbleupon,delicious,pinterest,buffer,print,email',
                    offsetLocation: 0,
                    center: 625,
                    floater: false
                });
                var a = $('#dcssb-1');
                buttonPosition(a);
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    buttonPosition(a);
                });
            });
            function buttonPosition(obj) {
                var top = $(document).scrollTop();
                var p = top > 400 ? { marginTop: '20px' } : { marginTop: (400 - top) + 'px' };
                obj.css(p);
            }
</script>
```

When I place the code in MasterPage or in a Page which uses a Masterpage I get this error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'dcSocialShare'
```

I have placed all the JS includes correctly in the the page, but when I use it without a materpage it works, why I get this error only when it's placed in the masterpage or in a page which uses a masterpage?

Comment: Are you sure the includes are loaded before the javascript which you have quoted?

Comment: What exactly do you do to "include it correctly"? Why don't you view the source of the page in the browser and make sure the `<script>` tag that you include the JS file is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to include your js files in `asp:ScriptManager` like the following

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/jquery.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```